# The word "Trial" for an app title in the App Store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Is it OK to state "Trial" in the title of my app in the App Store?
I know price mentions are considered illegal words (including "Free").

If it's not, how can one match customer exceptions regarding the app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 2.2 of [Apple's review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) says that trial apps don't belong in their App store.

Their do appear to be apps in the iOS App store that use the word "trial" for apps that support sport time trials, medical trials, and legal trials, etc.  So use of the word in that sense might potentially be allowed.

Comment: But trial are part of their subscription platform. So what am I missing? (e.g. Netflix)

Comment: The Netflix app isn't a trial app; instead, the video content appears to be.  But the app itself is still useful for managing expired subscriptions, viewing adverts, and etc.